# Google Tag Manager - Count visit on lazy load post

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a Wordpress page, and I developed an "Infinite Scroll" for posts. When I am reading a post and scroll to bottom, the page load another post using Ajax (and change the URL) but without windows refresh.

I need (my client) that when someone scroll down and a new post is loaded, that load count a visit on Google Tag Manager, as if that person should enter to that post directly.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try history change trigger. It often helps when the URL changes without page loads.

A proper solution here, however, would be modifying the lazy loading function to issue a dataLayer event whenever a new post is loaded.

Another hack for it would be using the visibility trigger. And use it for, let's say, your post headers. And then pass that header in an event.

Then you will be able to conduct classical per-post impressions-to-clicks analysis. CTR, basically.